# SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_society/server/main.lua:39: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')

Tags: lua, null, program-entry-point

Can anyone help me please, why do i keep getting this message?

```
SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_society/server/main.lua:39: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')
```

Comment: What's in line 39?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for late answer.. check your database, a job likely is missing a grade(jumps from 0,1,3,4,5 or something) or has a job grade too many(0,1,2,3,4,5,6 where 6 does not exist) or an empty spot, where the number simply is not present..

but maybe in the future add that its for a fivem server, not 100% clear for someone just looking, only know it because i recently fixed this for another server.